# how can I convert circleF object to array object using emgu c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, opencv, emgucv

I am new at EmguCV & C# and I have a project that find circles' info (centers' X & Y coordinates) from USB Camera. According to these coordinates, prototype machine moves rollers with stepper motor x-axis or y-axis.

I used CircleF with HoughCircles and found coordinates with this code:

> > CircleF[] circles = imgProcessed.HoughCircles(new Gray(100), new Gray(50), 2, imgProcessed.Height / 4, 30, 45)[0];

I want to create 2d array from CircleF to apply array process and  apply mathematical operations to circles' X and Y values.

I thought that if I convert "circles" CircleF to array, these processes are easier.
I know CircleF is a kind of array, but I cannot apply some array process (like sorting) on it. I want to sort X values of circles' centers from small to large. I cannot do that like Array.Sort(circles)

Does anybody help me about this situation?

or if it is possible to apply array process on CircleF, how can I apply?

Code samples would be useful. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "array process"? CircleF basically just "wraps" the center coordinate of the circle along with the radius and area. Take a look at the following which is taken from the Emgu.Cv.dll:

```
public struct CircleF : IEquatable<CircleF>
{
    public CircleF(PointF center, float radius);

    public double Area { get; }
    public PointF Center { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Radius")]
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(CircleF circle2);
}
```

So when iterating your array of CircleF structs you can:

```
for(int i=0;i < circles.Length;i++){
```

`var currCircleF = circles[i];`

`//do something with currCircleF, e.g. change radius,center,etc.`

}

Comment: "array process" means like sorting. for example, I want to sort X values of circles' centers from small to large. Icannot do that like Array.Sort(circles) or I want to get each X and Y values of centers to apply mathematical operations.

Comment: Well, since Array.Sort requires the class/struct to implement IComparable you could wrap CircleF in another struct implementing IComparable. Take a look at: http://pastebin.com/XkCXuVdR
Maybe it helps, but I'm not sure about the mathematical operations, maybe someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the array of circles according to the value of center X:

```
var sortedCircleFbyX = circles.OrderBy(c => c.Center.X).ToArray();
```

The result is an array of CircleF. You can then perform processing like:

```
//do more processing
foreach (var circleF in sortedCircleFbyX)
{
     MoveStepperMotor(circleF.Center);
}
```